# Error when importing pix2pix in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I tried to install pix2pix for a GAN in Google Colab.
The thing is, when trying to install pix2pix with
`!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git`,
I get this error:

```
  Resolved https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git to commit 1ca61321294cd2e97efc021ff1b3700b42befd0b
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried using another command, e.g.
`!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git`
but it provides the same error. If you have any hint to solve it or if you know another way to use pix2pix (as it seems to be an issue from pix2pix's side), let me informed about it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling with it in the future, I got the solution, which is:

```
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples
from examples.tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```